# systemd: How to wait for a network device provided dynamicly at runtime?

Tags: systemd, libvirt, virtual-network

We have a server (hypervisor) hosting many virtual machines controlled by libvirt. libvirt provides a virtual network for communication between the virtual machines and the hypervisor. This virtual network is established at runtime by `libvirtd.service` and called `sys-devices-virtual-net-virbr1.device`.

A few services, running on the hypervisor, should be bound to that virtual network, like IMAP, Database and so on.

The problem we face is that the services, running on the hypervisor, are started by systemd before the virtual network is setup and so the startup of the services failed. The current startup order are shown in this graph:

[systemd startup order graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6lyt.png)

For cases like this there are systemd directives, like

- `After=`
- `Required=`
- `Wants=`

and so on. But they don't help in my case. As far as I understood is the reason for this that the `sys-devices-virtual-net-virbr1.device` is created by `libvirtd.service` dynamically at runtime and not known to systemd at system startup. So the dependency can't be resolved at startup by systemd, since the `sys-devices-virtual-net-virbr1.device` network interface is not known.

Does systemd provides techniques to solve such issues?

Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a service unit as dependent of a device unit even if that device unit is not explicitely defined in another unit (e.g. it comes from udev).

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=sys-devices-virtual-net-virbr1.device
After=sys-devices-virtual-net-virbr1.device
```

As you can see in man systemd.unit

> BindsTo=

> ```
>  Configures requirement dependencies, very similar in style to
>  Requires=. However, this dependency type is stronger: in addition 
>  to the effect of Requires= it declares that if the unit bound to 
>  is stopped, this unit will be stopped too.
> ```

> ```
>  When used in conjunction with After= on the same unit the 
>  behaviour of BindsTo= is even stronger. In this case, the unit
>  bound to strictly has to be in active state for this unit to also 
>  be in active state
> ```